# Find and Replace text between /** and */ in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a large .cpp file where I want to remove all comment between the `/**` and the `*/` . This needs to work across lines as well.

I tried doing a regular Find and Replace using `\/.*? */` in the Find box and I found this

```
*/
int totalCount = 0;

/**
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: [`^\s*\/\*\*.+?\*\/`](https://regex101.com/r/Wrip0B/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookbehind and lookahead:

```
(?<=/\*\*)(.*?)(?=\*/)
```

Comment: be sure to check `. matches new line` in Notepad++